# How can I multiply two large matrices by corresponding columns and rows

Tags: r

I have two matrices for example:

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

> B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   10
[2,]    8   11
[3,]    9   12
```

and I want a vector called C whose element C[i]=A[i,]*B[,i], so the outcome should be:

```
> C
     [,1]
[1,]   76
[2,]  136
```

I used the for loop `for (i in 1:2) {C[i]=A[i,]%*%B[,i]}`. But it is very slow.
And I also tried `A%*%B` and take elements in the diagonal, and it just make my computer crash when the matrix is large.
Could you please give me some suggestions? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

A straight multiplication (not matrix multiplication but element-wise multiplication) could work for what we want. That gets the multiplications we want - after that we just want to take the sum of the rows.  If we need the result to be a column matrix we can convert to matrix.

```
> A <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
> B <- matrix(7:12, ncol = 2)
> B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   10
[2,]    8   11
[3,]    9   12
> rowSums(A * t(B))
[1]  76 136
> as.matrix(rowSums(A * t(B)))
     [,1]
[1,]   76
[2,]  136
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
mapply(function(a,b) sum(a*b), asplit(A, 1), asplit(B, 2))
# [1]  76 136
```